# c# ASP.NET Datalist and HTML radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, datalist, datalistitem

My site has language change control so when a language is clicked I reload the same page but with different language text, and if the user has already field in the form I have to reload the data.

I have managed to reload data into checkboxes, textbox but not with radio botton

Please see my code

I have a datalist and a radio button inside.

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlRole">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <input type="radio" id="rblRole" name="rblRole" value='<%# Eval("RoleCode") %>' />                      
                    <asp:Label ID="lbRole" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

I load the datalist, radio buttons

```
dlRole.DataSource = ...
dlRole.DataBind();
```

I save the radio button value into user session object

```
 user.Role = Request["rblRole"];
```

but when I reload the saved object into radio button, it cannot find the radio button object control.... radio button is always NULL. and I am not sure why

```
        foreach (DataListItem item in dlRole.Items)
        {
            HtmlInputRadioButton radio = (item.FindControl("rblRole") as HtmlInputRadioButton);                
            if (radio != null) <--- always nulll
            {
                if (radio.Value == user.Role.ToString())
                {
                  radio.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                  radio.Checked = false;
            }
        }
```

please let me know how to fix that
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
runat="server"
```

on you radio button otherwise it will not be accessible from the Code Behind.

Comment: I tried that before, and if I add runat=server, the buttons are not grouped, user can select more then one at a time.... any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Welcome to ASP.NET ;) This is an old bug (see here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316495) - if you do some searching you will find a few workarounds - the main one being to rewrite the name with a bit of JavaScript